# Volume to physical drive

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, hard-drive

```
QueryDosDevice(L"E:", DeviceName, MAX_PATH);
```

(E: is a SD card)

DeviceName is "\Device\HarddiskVolume3"

How do I "convert" it to something like `"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1"`

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you want to convert it to such format? Or do you just want to get the globally unique index of the device?

Comment: It isn't a drive, it really is only a volume.

Comment: I am trying to get some information with WMI. I need to know that so I can match with DeviceID from Win32_DiskDrive class

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Volumes are made up of one or more partitions, which reside on disks. So, E: doesn't necessarily map to a single disk in the system (think software RAID).

The way you map volumes to the PhysicalDrive names in Win32 is to first open the volume and then send IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS. This will give you a structure that has one DISK_EXTENT entry for every partition that the volume spans:

```
typedef struct _VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS {
  DWORD       NumberOfDiskExtents;
  DISK_EXTENT Extents[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
} VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS, *PVOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS;
```

The extents have a disk number in them:

```
typedef struct _DISK_EXTENT {
  DWORD         DiskNumber;
  LARGE_INTEGER StartingOffset;
  LARGE_INTEGER ExtentLength;
} DISK_EXTENT, *PDISK_EXTENT;
```

The DiskNumber is what goes into the PhsyicalDriveX link, so you can just sprintf that number with "\\.\PhysicalDrive%d"

-scott

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using WMI anyway, start with `Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`. On the `Win32_LogicalDisk` side, the Caption will be the drive letter. Then use `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` to see what physical drive holds that partition.