# QFile: cannot retrieve size from PHYSICALDRIVE

Tags: qt, qfile

I wrote a tool which was originally thought for analyzing hard disc images. Now I'm trying to use this tool for live analyzis of computer systems, means my tool tries to access the physical drive.

I implemented my tool in QT accessing the images using the QFile class. Instead of images I hand over the physical drive, under windows it is \.\PHYSICALDRIVE0.

I was wondering first I didnt get any errors, I can open the device, I can seek, get the position, almost everything. The only thing I have problems with is retrieving the drive size with size().

Some code example:

```
QFile file( "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0" );
file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly );

file.size(); //returns 0
```

I'm not too deep into QT, probably this is some easy thing. I would like to thank everybody who has an idea what is the reason.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure Qt can handle those, in any case it would read \\.\\P..., not \\.\P. Check with QFileInfo::exists() etc. if Qt finds the drive at all.

Comment: As I said, I can actually do everything except retrieving the disc size.

QFile::exists() returns false :( But how can file.open() return true?

Comment: Are you sure open() returns true? You don't check the return value... . Also, opening a drive doesn't make sense to me. Then, size() on a drive might just not do what you expect it to do. QFile::size() returns the size of files, not whole directory trees or drives. E.g, QFile("somedir").size() won't return the size of the contents of the directory, but the size of the directory _file_ itself (containing the index), which is usually only a couple of KB. So the OS might just return 0 for that drive node.

Answer (score 0):

[`QFileInfo`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#details) may be able to help you out.  It sounds like opening a read only file at that part of windows partition is allowed maybe even if it doesn't exist.  There might be a chance that the call of `GetLastError()` may give more information why a file size of zero was returned.

With `QFileInfo`, you can check to make sure it exists before it opens.

You may end up needing some platform specific calls to be able to work with Physical Drives:

[Volume to physical drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824221/volume-to-physical-drive)

It looks like there may be some example code of looking at partitions with [PartMod](https://sourceforge.net/p/partmodproject/code/27/tree/trunk/) on SourceForge.

As a side note of querying sizes of file folders, I thought it had to be cached somewhere by the operating system, or had to be calculated at the time of the query in many cases.  I know it seems like that happens when looking at folder properties in Windows or Get Info on OSX.

Also, looking at the [Volume to physical drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824221/volume-to-physical-drive) answers, there is a field there for the extent length.  I think this is what you are looking for.

Hope that helps.